# Using aggregate in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, aggregate

I'm trying to import my Excel file to google sheets but google sheets doesn't have the AGGREGATE function. This is the line I am trying to make happen
This is the function for Z2
=INDEX(V:V,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($2:$14)/(W$2:W$14=Y2),COUNTIF(Y$2:Y2,Y2)))

This is what I am trying to accomplish, I want Z to display the names listed on V based on the order on W. I have the order already ordered in Y but since there could be repeated numbers a simple match formula won't work.

[here is a visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hbkx.png)

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try, in Z2:

```
=sort(V2:V11,W2:W11,1)
```